# Determine if a language is regular from the first sight

Tags: regular-language

Is there a way to guess if a language is regular from the first sight? I.e. in order to choose proof methods, I have to have some hypothesis at first. Do you know any hints/patterns?

I need this to reduce time consumption: for instance, in order not to spend time on pumping lemma/Myhill–Nerode theorem, when in fact the language IS regular and I need to construct DFA/grammar.

The language is expressed as a set of all its words possible. For example:

$$
 L = \left\{ {(0)^{2n}(10)^{3k+1}1^m }, n, k, m ≥ 0 \right\}, \Sigma = \left\{{0,1}\right\}
$$

Comment: How about standard criteria like left-linear/right-linear grammar?

Comment: To say how the first sight may help, can you tell how the language you talking about is expressed? By the way, there is also [Computer Science.SE beta](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Imagine that you’re reading a word one symbol at a time. How much do you have to remember as you go along in order to decide whether the word is in the language? Is that amount bounded, or can it be arbitrarily large (as with the language of words of the form $0^n1^n$, for instance). If it’s bounded, you have a regular language. If it appears not to be bounded, you probably don’t have a regular language, though the impression that it’s unbounded may of course have been wrong.

Comment: Unlike the pumping lemma, Myhill-Nerode works in both directions: A language $L$ is regular if and only if the number of Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes is finite (the equivalence relation being $u \sim v$ iff for every $w$, the strings $uw$ and $vw$ are either both in $L$ or both not in $L$.)

Comment: @Ilya, I added an example showing how the language is expressed in my case.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, you could rewrite your comment as an answer, this looks like exactly what I have been looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Ted, I will practice using it vice versa. So far we have been taught just to use it in contradiction proofs.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, at least I'll be able to vote up for your idea.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, Myhill-Nerode is much easier to use for contradiction proofs than for showing a language is regular.

Comment: I’ve now done so.

Comment: Great, I voted up!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easiest Round-off Trick:

1. Look at the exponents of the different alphabets. Is there any relation between the different exponents?

   - **No.** The language is **regular** and **context-free**. eg: L= $a^m b^n$ with $m,n \geq 0$.
   - **Yes, one.** For instance, $L=a^m b^n$, with a relation like $m>n$, $m \neq n$, or $m<n$. These languages are **not regular**, but are **context-free** and accepted by a PDA. For a language with the relation $m=n$, you would need one counter to keep a count, inrementing it by $1$ for n-times for a and compare with b by decrementing by $1$ for n-times, until you get a $0$ for a match.
   - **Yes, multiple.** These languages are **not regular** and **not context-free** but they are **context-sensitive** and thus **recursive**. Note that not all recursive languages are context-sensitive. If you have more than one relation or need more than one counter, for instance, $L= a^m b^n c^k$ with $m=n=k$, you would need 2 such counters. First, you would count all a's and copy this count value to another counter. Then, compare with b by decrementing it n-times to get a $0$. Again, decrementing the other counter n-times to compare it with c and accept the language if both the counters are $0$.

Comment: Thank you for adding extra information about context-free languages. I needed it, too, although didn't ask it in my question.

Comment: That helps me alot in my next exam , thank you!

Comment: @Himanshu: Can you give an example explaining step 3b and/or 4.

Answer (score 7):

Imagine that you’re reading a word one symbol at a time. How much do you have to remember as you go along in order to decide whether the word is in the language? Is that amount bounded, or can it be arbitrarily large (as with the language of words of the form $0^n1^n$, for instance). If it’s bounded, you have a regular language. If it appears not to be bounded, you probably don’t have a regular language, though the impression that it’s unbounded may of course have been wrong.

Comment: Very good answer, thanks a lot! Unfortunately I can't mark all the answers as accepted, otherwise I would have done that here too.

Comment: @Umari: You're welcome.

Comment: Who is @umari ?

Comment: @Atul: Evidently an earlier screen name of the person now posting as petajamaja.

Answer (score 3):

One simple criterion that works in many cases is that if you see only *linear* functions in the exponents (like $2n$, $3k+1$, $m$ in your formula), *and* no variable appears more than once in the exponents, then the language is regular.  This is because a language like $\{ 0^{2n} : n \ge 0\}$ corresponds to the regular expression $(00)^*$.  A rigorous proof of this rule (which also needs to be stated more precisely before it can be proved) uses closure properties of regular languages, which you should also know.

Answer (score 0):

The rules of a regular grammar are in the form :-

For Right regular form:-   For Left regular form:-

```
(Terminal)->epsilon or (non-terminal)        |  (Terminal)->epsilon or (non-terminal) 

(Terminal)->(non-terminal)(Terminal)         |  (Terminal)->(Terminal)(non-terminal) 


A->phi                       |  A->phi
A->aA'|aA                    |  A->A'a|Aa
A'->a                        |  A->a
```